# Is it possible to install Ubuntu onto a computer where no other operating system exists?

Tags: installation, boot

My computer is a Toshiba satellite 7675d-s7104 model, and it has no operating system on it.

Is it possible to just boot Ubuntu from a flash drive?

Answer (score 4):

That is possible. There is no reason you should have an operating system preinstalled in order to try live media (like a live CD or a live flash drive).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it with:

[1. A USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) that is at least 2 gb

Or

[2. A CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD)

Comment: To clarify, you need a computer on which to create the Live USB or burn the Live CD.  But you can do that on any other computer!